# in-class non-static member initialization via std::is_convertible fails in gcc

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I compiled that with gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10), but it gives me an seemingly unrelated error.

is that possibly a compiler bug?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

struct test_class {
    bool B1 = std::is_convertible<std::output_iterator_tag, std::output_iterator_tag>::value; // error: invalid use of ‘::’

    //static const bool B1 = std::is_convertible<std::output_iterator_tag, std::output_iterator_tag>::value; // works fine

    //bool B1;
    //test_class() : B1(std::is_convertible<std::output_iterator_tag, std::output_iterator_tag>::value) {} // works fine
};

int main() {
    test_class a;
    std::cout << a.B1;
}
```

compiled via: name@machine:~$ g++ -std=c++14 example.cpp

MSVC 2015 is compiling just fine.

Comment: I think a bug of g++. Works well with version equal or greater than 6.1 (https://godbolt.org/g/Vf1Uaz) , but not with older version (https://godbolt.org/g/gFnL7j)

Comment: Parsing bug. Basically, it tried parsing the `<` as less-than, the `,` as separating two declarations, then crashed and burned on the `::`. Workaround is to parenthesize the whole thing.

Comment: Also, a reduced example would be something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ade774269f07ce20).